# Failed to write to disk tarantool, how to free up?

Tags: tarantool

I was inserting a huge amount of tuples to my space and ended up with tarantool telling me

> error: Failed to write to disk

on insert and delete operations.

What should I do to free up space, just for continue working with this instance. I don't care about data, if it's needed it can be deleted.

I tried:

```
my_space:truncate{}
```

but it was lead to the same error message. I'm new to unix systems(got freebsd in this case) and tarantool in general.

**EDIT**

my config

```
box.cfg {
  listen = 3305;
  background = true;
  slab_alloc_arena = 5;
  slab_alloc_minimal = 16;
  slab_alloc_maximal = 1048576;
  slab_alloc_factor = 1.06;
  snapshot_period = 3600;
  snapshot_count = 6;
  panic_on_snap_error = true;
  panic_on_wal_error = true;
  snap_io_rate_limit = nil;
  wal_mode = "write";
  wal_dir_rescan_delay = 2.0;
  readahead = 16320;
  log_level = 5;
  logger_nonblock = true;
  too_long_threshold = 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the snapshot daemon, a feature in Tarantool which automatically recycles space used by the write ahead log (.xlog) files. 
Here's the relevant chapter in the  manual https://tarantool.org/doc/book/configuration/index.html#snapshot-daemon

Meanwhile, you could manually remove all *.xlog files (simply rm -rf *.xlog, but keep one which is open, the one with the biggest number in its name), and make a snapshot (send SIGUSR1 signal to the daemon).

Comment: I have this lines on box config `snapshot_period = 3600;
      snapshot_count = 6;
      wal_mode = "write";`. I found directory with *.xlog files which you mentioned on path  _/var/db/tarantool/instancename_ [link](https://tarantool.org/doc/book/administration.html#configuring-for-tarantoolctl). Also I have 6 *.snap files on this directory. Also I have 23 .xlog files before newest *.snap file ordering by changed date descending.

Comment: I didn't tried sending signal to the daemon, but tried making a snapshot by this command `box.snapshot()`. [https://tarantool.org/doc/book/box/admin.html](https://tarantool.org/doc/book/box/admin.html). Got `error: can't save snapshot, errno 28 (No space left on device)`. I will try to manually remove *.xlog files and then try to make snapshot as you suggested

Comment: I manually removed *.xlog files as you said and doesn't touched *.snap files, after this `box.snapshot()` finally returned **ok** and `my_space:truncate{}` also **successfully** executed! In directory added new *.snap file increasing count of snapshots to 7. I'm still wondering how it worked out in terms of disk space cause my older snapshot's size is 1.7Gb and as i said i didn't delete any snapshot files. My problem is solved, thank you for the help, @Kostja. I provided details in my investigation, maybe it's unnecessary, but maybe it will help someone to better understand what is going on.